# What are Xcode documentation files for?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode7

[image]

Hey guys, I'm asking this because I don't know how to use them or what are they for, I tried opening the "Xcode 7.2 Documentation", but it just opened a blank page:

[image]

So, I'd like to know how to use and if I should download them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download them, you will see the content when using Help -> Documentation and API Reference, or clicking links in the Quick Help area, even when your computer does not have internet access.